# How can I add cents in my Number to Word conversion

Tags: javascript

I already have a code that can convert numbers to words but when I input a decimal point it is counted as "0" and I also need to add cents in my conversion.

```
function numberToEnglish( n ) {

    var string = n.toString(), units, tens, scales, start, end, chunks, chunksLen, chunk, ints, i, word, words, and = 'and';

    /* Remove spaces and commas */
    string = string.replace(/[,|.]/g,"");
    /* Check number if Zero? */
    if( parseInt( string ) === 0 ) {
        return 'Zero';
    }

    /* Array of units as words */
    units = [ '', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen' ];

    /* Array of tens as words */
    tens = [ '', '', 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety' ];

    /* Array of scales as words */
    scales = [ '', 'Thousand', 'Million', 'Billion', 'Trillion', 'Quadrillion', 'Quintillion', 'Sextillion', 'Septillion', 'Octillion', 'Nonillion', 'Decillion', 'Undecillion', 'Duodecillion', 'Tredecillion', 'Quatttuor-decillion', 'Quindecillion', 'Sexdecillion', 'Septen-decillion', 'Octodecillion', 'Novemdecillion', 'Vigintillion', 'Centillion' ];

    /* Split user arguemnt into 3 digit chunks from right to left */
    start = string.length;
    chunks = [];
    while( start > 0 ) {
        end = start;
        chunks.push( string.slice( ( start = Math.max( 0, start - 3 ) ), end ) );
    }

    /* Check if function has enough scale words to be able to stringify the user argument */
    chunksLen = chunks.length;
    if( chunksLen > scales.length ) {
        return '';
    }

    /* Stringify each integer in each chunk */
    words = [];
    for( i = 0; i < chunksLen; i++ ) {

        chunk = parseInt( chunks[i] );

        if( chunk ) {

            /* Split chunk into array of individual integers */
            ints = chunks[i].split( '' ).reverse().map( parseFloat );

            /* If tens integer is 1, i.e. 10, then add 10 to units integer */
            if( ints[1] === 1 ) {
                ints[0] += 10;
            }

            /* Add scale word if chunk is not zero and array item exists */
            if( ( word = scales[i] ) ) {
                words.push( word );
            }

            /* Add unit word if array item exists */
            if( ( word = units[ ints[0] ] ) ) {
                words.push( word );
            }

            /* Add tens word if array item exists */
            if( ( word = tens[ ints[1] ] ) ) {
                words.push( word );
            }

            /* Add 'and' string after units or tens integer if: */
            if( ints[0] || ints[1] ) {

                /* Chunk has a hundreds integer or chunk is the first of multiple chunks */
                if( ints[2] || (i + 1) > chunksLen ) {
                    words.push( and );
                }

            }

            /* Add hundreds word if array item exists */
            if( ( word = units[ ints[2] ] ) ) {
                words.push( word + ' Hundred' );
            }

        }

    }
        return words.reverse().join( ' ' );
}
```

When I input 123,234.20, I expect the output of One Hundred and Twenty Three Thousand Two Hundred Thirty Four and Twenty Cents but the actual output is Twelve Million Three Hundred and Twenty Three Thousand Four Hundred and Twenty

https://jsfiddle.net/qwz78khf/

Answer (score 0):

You treated the dot and coma as the same thing (replaced both with "")
try separating them so that your code checks for dot too.

this line to be exact

```
string = string.replace(/[,|.]/g,"");
```

your number became 12323420 instead of 123234.20

Comment: Yes but I also need to have a cents conversion